# jQuery dynamic button selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, dynamic, selector

Is there a reason this won't work? It works the first time, the variable gets updated (and I can see it), yet it doesn't work on anything after the first one.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
 
  var question = 1;
  $("ul#question"+question+" li").on( "click", function(e) { 
    $(this).addClass("test" + question);
    question++; 
  });
  
});
```

What I'm trying to do is use the same button actions for 6 different buttons. It has to be this way so that I can use off() on each one, separately, as I go.

Otherwise I have to write the same code out 6 times. Perhaps there's a better way, I just don't understand why this isn't working.

Thanks

Comment: write the html code also.

Comment: Thanks, I know what to use now, and it's actually done, I am just trying to understand why this didn't work along the way.

Comment: you can of by `$(".button_class").on("click",function(){$(this).addClass("off");});`

Comment: @theinvisible there is no need to use loop at all

Comment: The variable 'question' is unchanged by the time event listeners are being assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

incrementing the variable will not change the selector of the event handler. You could use a class selector and then test the id in the event handler:

```
var question = 1;
  $("ul.question li").on( "click", function(e) {
    if ($(this).closest("ul").attr("id") === "question"+question) {
        $(this).addClass("test" + question);
        question++; 
    }
  });
```

UPDATE

Or even:

```
var question = 1;
  $("ul[id^='question'] li").on( "click", function(e) {
    if ($(this).closest("ul").attr("id") === "question"+question) {
        $(this).addClass("test" + question);
        question++; 
    }
  });
```

Comment: exactly +1, in current case there is no need of loop , we can select current element by `this` :)

Answer (score 0):

this is just my imagination since i don't know your html looks like.

you just create for 1 action when you have 6 button with different id.
try to use `.each` with same classname in your button.

```
var question = 1;
$('.question').each(function() {
    $("ul#question"+question+" li").on( "click", function(e) { 
        $(this).addClass("test" + question);
    });
question++; 
});
```